# Select values in python DataFrame based on multiple condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with three columns, productId, date, price. Now I want to get the latest price for each product, if there are multiple price for latest date, get the mean value. How can I do this?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"productId":[1,2,1,2,3],
        "date":["2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-02","2021-01-03","2021-01-03"],
        "price":[12.0,11.3,11.0,9.8,8.7]}
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried following code but it throws an exception that says `Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

```
latest_price = df.groupby("productId")["date"].max()
df = df.loc[df["date"] == latest_price ].copy()

df["price"] = df.groupby("productId")["price"].transform("mean")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the products by their id and take the mean

```py
df = df.groupby(['productId', 'date']).mean().reset_index()
```

Now you have all the means, by sorting the dates in descending order you will get the latest prices first in the dataframe. If you then drop the duplicates productIds you will have deleted every price that is not the latest.

```py
df = df.sort_values('date', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('productId')
df

productId   date    price
2   2   2021-01-03  9.8
3   3   2021-01-03  8.7
0   1   2021-01-02  11.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) a function to compute the *latest mean/price* then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) it to each product :

```
# if needed
# df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

latest_price = (
    df.groupby("productId").apply(
        lambda g: g.loc[g["date"].eq(g["date"].max()), "price"].mean())
)

df["price"] = df["productId"].map(latest_price)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   productId       date  price
0          1 2021-01-02   11.5
1          2 2021-01-02    9.8
2          1 2021-01-02   11.5
3          2 2021-01-03    9.8
4          3 2021-01-03    8.7
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there a reason use this approach instead of Kevin Spagetti's solution?

Comment: Because it seems OP want to preserve the shape (*same number of rows/columns*) of the initial `df`. Also, many roads lead to Rome, the sorting/duplicates approach is fine too ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it's a bit complex for me.